# Ruby - loading data in a loop causing memory increase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, memory-leaks

I have a memory issue with a loop in ruby. This code is executed using a Scheduled Job, and the memory is increasing linearly over the time, like if something loaded is retained in memory and never cleaned?

```
# cars entries is around 2000 entries here
cars.each do |car|
   myService.create_car_in_db(car)
end
```

and

```
def create_car_in_db(car)
  # I'm suspecting this car_models to be never cleaned ?
  car_models = get_car_models(car)

  car_models.each do |model|
    CarModelData.create!(
      attr_1: model.attr_1,
      attr_2: model.attr_2
    )
  end

end
```

Is there a way in Ruby to force the GC to clean the memory?
I'm suspecting the car_models loaded each time to grow and grow in memory without being never cleaned?

Comment: The first thing you should do is use [`.find_each`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) instead to load the data in  batches so you don't exhaust the available memory. Then you can investigate if you have a memory leak. If you're just copying simple data from one table to another and don't need validations there are also a lot more efficient ways to do this like a mass insert.

Comment: Hi @max cars is not an Active record collection, only data fetched from an external service. You mean for car_models right ?

Comment: Ok that changes it somewhat. Does the external service have any kind of paging? We have very little to go by here  so its impossible to say why or why not the object is being recycled.  You can interact with the garbage collector with the GC module. https://blog.appsignal.com/2021/11/17/practical-garbage-collection-tuning-in-ruby.html

Comment: Is it a good practice to add a GC.start at the beginning of the cars.each loop ?

Comment: No - not really. You should probally find out why the code isn't working as intended.

Comment: hey @wawanopoulos what is inside `get_car_models ` method?
Also, please provide the `CarModelData` class code.

Also, you might try using https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import gem to initialize and validate and then batch_insert the collection of `CarModelDatas`. Note that if there are any callbacks in the model you'll need to call them manually because AR-import gem skips them.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't force `GC.start`, @wawanopoulos provide more code, most likely the "leak" happening due something outside of the code above is memoizing results, e.g. `get_car_models` or something in `myService`